# Objective-C - Given a UINib instance how can I initialize my custom UIView?

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uinib

I have a Custom UIView that I want to initialize from a nib.
I don't have access to the name of the nib, all I have is an instance of UINib.

How can I initialize my UIView using this UINib object?

**I don't want to use loadNibNamed method in NSBundle**

Comment: hm http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UINib_Ref/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 2):

If the `UINib` object already exists, send it an `-instantiateWithOwner:options:` message.

Comment: That didn't work, I tried to call methods on my custom UIView and it crashes because the final object is type of UINib instead of my subclass of UIView

Comment: This should work, if you have the UINib already -instantiateWithOwner:options: returns an array of top-level objects in the nib it's associated with.